# UISearchBar cancel button not reloading original array

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, searchbar

I have a TableView based application where I have incorporated a UISearchBarDelegate.  The application works as intended.  The tableview is displayed with all data, along with the UISearchBar.  When text is entered into the search field, the list is narrowed down to match that of the text entered.

The problem that I am experiencing is that when I click the cancel button, the keyboard disappears as it should but the original array is not returned....It still shows the searched item(s) as they appear.

In my searchBarCancelButtonClicked section, I have the following code:

```
- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)SearchBar 
{
    SearchBar.text = nil;

    [SearchBar resignFirstResponder];

    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

I would assume that the `[tableView reloadData]` section should reload the data from the original array when the cancel button is clicked but it does not do that.  Any ideas as to what I might be doing wrong here?

Also, here is my cellForRowAtIndexPath.  When comparing to other examples, it seems like I am doing things correctly....With nothing obvious sticking out at me.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MyIndentifier"];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

}


StateDetail *cd;
if(isFiltered)
    cd = [self.searchStates objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
else 
    cd = [self.listOfStates objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.textLabel.text = cd.stateName;


return cell;
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the problem is in the way you generate your table results. Are you using a temporary (filtered) array to store the data for when the user runs a search? It'd be helpful to see your cellForRowAtIndexPath method, etc.

First suggestion: make sure that all of your tableView delegate methods check for whether or not the user is searching. For example, you can have a BOOL userSearching that you set as appropriate, and then check every time to see if the user is searching. Then, you can pick your cell from the correct array (if you're using two, as I described above).

Second suggestion: use a SearchDisplayController, rather than a standalone searchbar. It handles most of this functionality for you. If you use this strategy, then you can check for whether or not the user is searching in methods like cellForRowAtIndexPath with:

```
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.tableView)... {
    //user is searching, so act appropriately
} else {
    //user is not searching...
}
```

(Here, tableView is the local variable passed into the method. I'm writing that code from memory, so apologies for any errors.)

Let me know if you need any more clarification on either of these strategies.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply to my posting.  I appreciate it.  In regards to the array, I am using two arrays (One as the main array and another as the search results array)  Both are declared and synthesized in my .h and .m files.  I have updated my original posting to include my cellForRowAtIndexPath.  I have looked over some other examples using search bars but nothing glaring is sticking out to be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {


    isSearching = YES;


    self.searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;

    for (UIView *subView in searchBar.subviews) {
        if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            UIButton *cancelButton = (UIButton*)subView;

            [cancelButton setTitle:@"hi" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }
    self.searchBar.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    UITextField *textField = [self.searchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];

    textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;

}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    NSLog(@"Text change - %d",isSearching);

    for (UIView *subview in searchBar.subviews)
    {
        if ([subview conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)])
        {
            [(UITextField *)subview setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeNever];
        }
    }
    //Remove all objects first.
    [filteredContentList removeAllObjects];

    if([searchText length] != 0) {
        isSearching = YES;
      //  [self searchTableList];


        if([searchBar.placeholder isEqualToString:@"Search by course name"]){
        NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"courseName CONTAINS[cd] %@",_searchBar.text];

        filteredContentList = [[listArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate] mutableCopy];
        }
       else  if([searchBar.placeholder isEqualToString:@"Search by category name"]){
            NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"category CONTAINS[cd] %@",_searchBar.text];

            filteredContentList = [[listArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate] mutableCopy];
        }

    }
    else {
        isSearching = NO;
       // [searchBar resignFirstResponder];


    }
  //  [self.tableView reloadData];
  //  [searchBar resignFirstResponder];

    [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    NSLog(@"Cancel clicked");
    self.searchBar.text=@"";
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    isSearching=NO;
     [self.tableView reloadData];


}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    NSLog(@"Search Clicked");
   // [self searchTableList];
   //

    [self.tableView reloadData];
[searchBar resignFirstResponder];


}
```

Here "isSearching" is bool values,
"listArray" is initial array,
"filteredContentList" is search array.